# Importance of power factor

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, electromagnetism, electric-machine

I understand the difference between reactive power, but why is power factor so important? A system with low PF draws more current; well wouldn't a larger load, be it resistive or reactive, draw a larger current anyway?

No analogies for the answer please, use all the math and rigor you want.

Comment: PF is the “sum” of bad things, cos phi due to lagging or leading current which will cause reactive power, and harmonic distortion or overtones. Both are undesirable for the grid.

Comment: Low PF brings higher currents. Higher currents bring higher load for the same "active" power. Now look at the problem from a perspective of electricity generation and/or distribution companies. Would you be happy to use unnecessarily larger cables? Or, if you somehow sized the cables for unity PF, would you be happy to have them hot (due to the increased loss) and therefore maintenance more frequent? Or would you be happy when the generators' load increase? Or would you be happy when you are billing the household customers for active energy only but they bring a high reactive load to you?

Comment: I should have written "values below 1.0" since high PF is desirable.

Comment: The important difference from a larger load is : you can bill more for a larger load.

Answer (score 2):

It's a quirk of the way that the electricity supply industry has developed that domestic consumers are only billed for the active power they use.

Fortunately, this matches most of the generator's costs, the active power relates to the fuel required to drive the generators.

However, the transmission costs do not follow the active power, but the current that is transmitted, in sizes of cable required, and cooling for transformers.

This means that those responsible for the transmission network need to rely on regulations to improve the power factor of the loads, to reduce the ratio of current supplied to active power used, rather than financial logic.

The reactive power just sloshes back and forth between the generator and the load. There are two energy aspects of this. First, the generator has to supply the stored energy that is 'sloshing' back and forth. This is a relatively minor one-off supply of energy when the bad load starts to require some reactive power, that we can ignore. Second, the generator has to continually supply the losses, the I<sup>2</sup>R, that this reactive power causes in the transmission network. These losses are real power, that have to be generated and paid for with fuel, and are on-going and significant.

The transmission company will be responsible for paying for these losses, although often they will also be the generating company.

These losses influence the efficiency of the transmission network, yet are not under their control, nor can be billed to domestic consumers. That is the argument for legislation to control the power factor of commercially available consumer loads, like PC power supplies and (now almost completely gone) inductor-ballasted flourescent tubes. Large industrial consumers of power do tend to get billed for bad power factor loads.

In summary, power input is needed into the generator for both real and reactive power delivery, but different amounts.

| customer receives | generator requires steady state mechanical input of |
| --- | --- |
| 1 kW of real power | 1 kW (thermodynamically irreducible) + transmission losses on 1 kW + generator efficiency losses on both of the above (losses can be improved towards zero with shorter transmission distance and/or by better equipment |
| 1 kVA of reactive power | transmission losses on 1 kVA + generator efficiency losses on the above (losses can be improved towards zero with shorter transmission distance and/or by better equipment |

Comment: "the active power relates to the fuel required to drive the generators." Wait where does reactive power come from?

Comment: So does a generator "create" reactive power?

Comment: @JirhsKumar in two ways, one significant, the other not, see my edit.

Comment: So you're saying that it doesn't cost to generate reactive power?

Comment: @JirhsKumar Your continued questioning was useful. How is that table on my answer looking?

Comment: Makes sense now, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in your question, a power factor less than 1 means that more current is being drawn from the system than the minimum to supply the active power load. That results in increased power losses in the power system and need for larger cable current capacity.

Additionally, inductive reactive power flows result in additional voltage drop in the power system, requiring more voltage regulation equipment necessary in order for the utility to maintain voltage within their stated service range. At the high-voltage transmission level, inductive reactive power flows reduce the amount of power that can be transferred along long power lines.

Only active power accomplishes "work" in the physics sense, so reactive power loads create greater expense for the power system for the reasons listed above while not providing any additional benefit to the customer.

Because the power system (transmission lines & transformers) are mostly reactive impedances, there is a strong coupling between reactive power flows and voltage regulation. Therefore, there is value to the power system to have devices/customers/generators that are able to adjust their reactive power in order to regulate voltage on the system.

There are many excellent power system analysis textbooks such as those by Bergen & Vittal or Stevenson & Grainger that give the background needed to understand these issues.

Comment: Isn't reactive power doing "work" too? The reactance of an inductor is the opposition it offers to ac voltages isn't it?

Comment: @JirhsKumar Work is defined as joule or watt-second. Since current and voltage is out of phase, no work is beefing accomplished, just losses in the system.